# JQuery submits the form on second or third click - Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I can't figure out why is validation not working on the first click but later.

I've add `validate` plugin to `JS` file so form is being validated after click.

As you can see, the validator is set when document is ready. Then, when the form is clicked, the validator checks, whether the form is valid.

```
function submit(form) {
    var formData = new FormData($(form).get(0));
    alert('Thank you for your message! Our support will reply as soon as possible.');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/contact-us-ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });
    $("#contact-us-form").submit(function (b) {
        b.preventDefault();
        this_form = $(this);

        $("#contact-us-form").validate({
            rules: {
                sender: {
                    required: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                sender: {
                    required: "Short description can't be empty. Please fill this field."
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "Please choose current language."
                },
                message: {
                    require_from_group: "Either fill this form with a text or attach a file (below)."
                }
            }, submitHandler: function (this_form) {
                submit(this_form);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: would you provide jsfiddle for this

Comment: The `return false;` in the `submit` function doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @ParagBhayani I've finally figured out where the problem was. I've answered this question. The code is not nice but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've figure out where the problem was. After first click, it just added the `validator` and on the second click, the `form` was validated and then submitted.

Here is the working code:

```
function submit(form) {
    var formData = new FormData($(form).get(0));
    alert('Thank you for your message! Our support will reply as soon as possible.');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/contact-us-ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function attachValidate() {
        $("#contact-us-form").validate({
            rules: {
                sender: {
                    required: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                sender: {
                    required: "Short description can't be empty. Please fill this field."
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "Please choose current language."
                },
                message: {
                    require_from_group: "Either fill this form with a text or attach a file (below)."
                }
            }, submitHandler: function (this_form) {
                submit(this_form);
            }
        });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });
    attachValidate();
    $("#contact-us-form").submit(function (b) {
        b.preventDefault();
        $(this).validate();
        });

});
```